# Batch ping to find fastest server

Tags: networking, ping

I have a list of about 200 IP addresses in a file. I want to know which one I have the lowest ping to, as they are game servers. Is there some way I can ping all of them and have the output be the server with the lowest ping?

For example:

```
> ./pingtest ips.txt
Fastest IP: XX.XX.XXX.XXX with a ping of XXms
```

I am running Windows but I have cygwin installed and can use linux if there is no other option. Thanks!

Comment: While it is completely possible, I would comment that what you are doing is finding the most responsive server at that point in time and may or may not actually indicate a better network performance over the course of your game.

Comment: Start here: [Ping every IP address in a text file?](http://superuser.com/questions/589644/ping-every-ip-address-in-a-text-file)