# Windows batch (.bat) file terminated automatically

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I've tested the following code based on discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/589644/ping-every-ip-address-in-a-text-file)

Unfortunately both codes (in .bat) has been terminated automatically and command prompt has been closed right after I executed it.

What caused this issue?

Even thought there is a `pause` at the end of the code, windows terminal simply closed right after that.

**[code from foxidrive](https://superuser.com/a/589645/1026801)**

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (computerlist.txt) do ping -n 1 %%a >nul && (echo %%a ok) || (echo %%a failed to respond) 
pause
```

**[Code from ElektroStudios](https://superuser.com/a/589646/1026801)**

```
@Echo OFF

For /F "Usebackq Delims=" %%# in (
    "List.txt"
) do (
    Echo+
    Echo [+] Pinging: %%#

    Ping -n 1 "%%#" 1>nul && (
        Echo     [OK]) || (
        Echo     [FAILED])
)

Pause
```

Btw, I run this code from CMD, not by executing .bat directly and the CMD still get terminated right after that.

Comment: You can use timeout followed by a number instead.

Comment: Both code snippets run smoothly using  full path to a valid `.txt` file. Change `echo off` to `echo ON` an launch the batch file from an open `cmd` window (instead of double-click). Perhaps there could be something unusual in the computer list file?

Comment: @JosefZ, I run this code from CMD, not by executing .bat directly and the CMD still get terminated right after that.

Comment: @Overmind, thanks tried that but still didn't work

Comment: You mean the timeout does not happen at all ? That could mean somewhere in the code something breaks and the file never reaches the end.

Comment: AFAIK, an open `cmd` windows does not spontaneously close 
 unless you explicitly use the [`exit` command](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html). Please [edit] the question and provide a [complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Instead of a sample code copied&pasted from other pages, share really used code, really used file names `computerlist.txt` and/or `"List.txt"` as well as **really used names of failing .bat (or .cmd) files**.

Comment: Apply `echo ON` in your batch and then try `cmd /K yourbatch.bat`.